# Why creating index in CoreData will end up duplicated index (with different name) in SQLite file?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I was wondering did anyone of you come across this strange situation?

I tried to index a property in entity.

For instance, for entity named `NSPlainNote`, I try to create an index named `index_plain_note_label`, on property `label`.

This is how it looks like.

[image]

The property of the `label` also seem pretty straightforward.

[image]

However, if I inspect the content of the generated SQLite file.

[image]

It seems that 2 same indices with different name are created.

```
CREATE INDEX Z_NSPlainNote_index_plain_note_label ON ZNSPLAINNOTE (ZLABEL COLLATE BINARY ASC)

CREATE INDEX Z_NSPlainNote_label ON ZNSPLAINNOTE (ZLABEL COLLATE BINARY ASC)
```

If we observe carefully, such duplication also happen in all other index with 1 property like

1. NSPlainNote's order
2. NSPlainNote's sticky
3. NSTabInfo's order

Such duplication does not happen on index with 2 properties, or index with unique constraint.

Seem like an undesired outcomes. As, having index will slow down write speed. So, in theory, having duplicated index will slow down write speed x2.

May I know why it is so? Is there any step which I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Interesting - there are no duplicates when I try it, but (weirdly) when going through a migration, CD does attempt to DROP the duplicate indexes.  The names of the duplicates tally with those which were used in the past for the previous indexing solution (NSAttributeDescription's now-deprecated `isIndexed`).   Is it possible your label attribute was previously marked `isIndexed`?

Comment: @pbasdf I guess not. I updated the question with the screenshot of `label` property. My project is a brand new project which has not released to public. No migration has been done before.

Comment: @pbasdf May I know, what version of XCode are u using? Thanks.

Comment: Using Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507) running iOS 14.5 on the iPhone 12 Pro Max simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You have done nothing wrong. Every time you create an index, `CoreData` does following -

1. Create the index you defined - `index_plain_note_label` in this case.
2. Create different indices (if they don't exist) for all the properties used in that index - `label` property index in this case.

---

###### Why does it need to do so?

> Not sure. `CoreData` has it's own way dealing with things and we shouldn't need to worry about how it facilitates what it does.

---

###### Tests

1. Try creating one index with single property.
2. Try creating another index with 2 other properties NOT included in #1.

You will see that it will create 5 indices in total

1. 2 indices that you defined
2. (1 property index for `index #1` + 2 properties indices for `index #2`)